# read excel file in j2me

Tags: excel, file, java-me

i have excel file , i want to use it like data base on j2me . how can i read excel file in j2me ?
thanks

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exporting it as an easily-parsable format such as CSV and reading that instead.